# Full width browser div's

Tags: html, css, html4

Recently i found out how you could do that the div filled the whole page.
But i used this method:

```
#fullWidthHeader {
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
}
```

But when i use the `position: fixed;` the other divs get stuck under it and
just gets messed up.

Is there anyway i can do full width browser div but without 
`position: fixed;` or the `box-shadow` method ?

Can i do like the background method --> `background-size: cover;`
or do i have to use `position: fixed;`

**EDIT**

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2vMP.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: By default divs are block level elements and 100% of the width of their parent.

Comment: Just remove the position: fixed. They are full width by default.

Comment: Screenshot --> http://imgur.com/a/aFfc5#2

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Liam_rab3/W6m4E/

Comment: I want the header div to cover the whole page -->http://imgur.com/43T0jZX

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a padding-top to the elements under the header to account for this space.

So if #fullWidthHeader.height = 100px

content under it would be:

```
.content{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no, i only want #fullWidthHeader to cover the hole page from left to right, like here > http://imgur.com/43T0jZX

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your full width header, with your width set to 100%, add `display:table;`. It should work. You dont need any fixed position, relative will do just fine.